# Are these adjectives coordinate or cumulative

Tags: adjectives

I'm designing a board game and I've run into an issue regarding a string of adjectives that come up frequently in the game. Sadly, I'm a non-native speaker, so I thought it best to reach out and be sure.

The sentence is "target 1 other willing living creature within 5 squares."

As far as I understand, you seperate coordinate adjectives with commas while cumulative adjectives aren't seperated by anything (except for a space).

My question comes down to whether the above adjectives - "other," "willing," and "living" - are coordinate or cumulative? Where, if anywhere, should I put commas?

Comment: Leaving out commas between coordinate adjectives is a very minor mistake in English, and putting in commas between cumulative adjectives is also a very minor mistake. I think that technically, *willing* and *living* are probably coordinate adjectives. But if I was writing this sentence, I'd leave the comma between them out (I can't say why). However, there isn't anything wrong with putting it in.

Comment: I should say that *other* is definitely a cumulative adjective here, so it shouldn't have a comma after it. But don't worry about it too much. Even native English speakers don't always follow this rule.

Comment: @rocketzombiesboardsgame. Your example has what is called 'stacked' modification (your 'cumulative adjectives') as evidenced by the lack of punctuation. If commas are added, it becomes a coordination of adjectives. There is often a difference in meaning between the two types, so you first need to decide on your intended meaning and then include punctuation if appropriate.

Comment: Does your game allow for willing *dead* (or undead) creatures? If not, then I would just say *willing*. If it *does* then, in the context of the game, they could certainly be cumulative—in the sense that there is a contrast to be made between willing living creatures and willing dead creatures. Especially if you talk about willing dead creatures elsewhere.  (Or just say *willing humans* as opposed to *willing zombies*. I just noted your username.)